# SAML2 token signing in Azure AD

Tags: azure, saml-2.0, azure-active-directory

To set a little bit of context, we are using [Azure AD SAML2 support](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn195591.aspx) to log into our site using Office365 credentials.

Reading the metadatas documentation, I have 2 questions:

[This document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn195592.aspx#Anchor_2) states:

> A federation metadata document published by Azure AD can have multiple signing keys , such as when Azure AD is preparing to update the signing certificate. When a federation metadata document includes more than one certificate, a service that is validating the tokens should support all certificates in the document.

Does this mean that the SAML2 auth token response signature must be checked against all the listed certificates, and considered valid if any one of them matches?

[This document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn641920.aspx) states:

> This topic discusses what you need to know about the public keys that are used in Azure AD to sign security tokens. It is important to note that these keys rollover on a 6 week schedule. In an emergency, a key could be changed much sooner than 6 weeks. All applications that use Azure AD should be able to programmatically handle the key rollover process.

Does this 6-week update schedule concern SAML2 token signature? If so, why are the certificates listed in the metadatas valid for way longer?

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary to validate the signature against all of the keys, but if you do that and the signature validates, then it should be considered valid.

You can use the ds:KeyInfo inside ds:Signature to determine the key to use deterministically.

Comment: Good point, although selecting the appropriate certificate before validating can be problematic because the C# SAML2 libraries we tested don't separate the SAML2 token parsing step from the signature validation step :/ Still trying to find a good low level C# SAML2 relying party library that exposes token (de)serialization and validation for SSO and SLO, and metadatas generation.

Comment: That is an excellent observation and one reason why we have delayed the release of the SAML libraries. The separation of signature validation is clean in JWT, we want the same for SAML, but we need some pieces such as EnvelopedSignatureReader, etc. It is in our plans, but we don't have a hard date yet.